# unable to set environment property in fitnesse setup page

Tags: fitnesse

I have been trying to set a environment variable property for DB connection parameters via a fitnesse suite setup page. 
I have tested this by setting the environment variable on an individual test page, and when I do this it does get resolved in my fixture API. But when I remove it from the test page and include it in the fitnesse setup page, it can't be resolved in my fixture API for some reason. 
This is the COMMAND_PATTERN string I have included to add the environment property: 
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {java -cp %p -Ddbadapter.config=classpath:/properties/fiAdapter-config.properties %m}

So this very string is correctly resolved when defined on a test page, but I move it out to the setup test page (which I know is successfully passing down other page level params to the tests), its not resolvable in my fixture API.

I have also tried specifying this property on startup of the fitnesse server: 
java -jar  -Dadapter.config=classpath:/properties/fiAdapter-config.properties fitnesse.jar -p 6538

and this doesn't isnt working for me either. The only way I can get this working is by specifying the parameter on each test page and that is defeating the purpose of using a properties file for this.

Any idea on what is causing this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Variables are set by looking through direct ancestry, rather than through siblings or even SetUp pages.  I generally define them either in the environment before running FitNesse or through the FrontPage or the Suite page that contains the tests that need it.

As far as I know, SetUp processes as a part of the page.  And I can see why you chose that, but I don't think it is as reliable a location for defining variables as a direct ancestor page.

Additionally, if you are using the COMMAND_PATTERN variable, I'm pretty sure you have to define the variable you want to send to it before you change the COMMAND_PATTERN.  And the command pattern cannot be changed multiple times in a single suite execution.

Comment: thank you for your response, this explains why my test setup page is not the right place for defining this environment property. Can you please give me an example of how you would define this variable via the fitnesse front page or in the environment. I have tried setting it on the command line on starting the fitnesse server, and it is still not getting resolved. With regards to the fitnesse front page, would you create a page on this front page to define the property??

Comment: I would add the variable definition to the contents of the FrontPage itsefl (assuming your test page is below FrontPage).

  !define DEBCONECT {setting}

Then pass reference that later using ${DBCONNECT}